# How to prevent player from shooting projectiles after ammo depletion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, projectile

I'm making a game that is similar to Space Shooter, and I would like to know how to prevent a player from shooting projectiles AFTER the ammo has depleted.

The two scripts below controls my player's movement and actions, and decreases the current projectile count each time the player hits spacebar.

Player script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

//Movement speed of Player sprite
public float Speed = 20.5f;
//GameObject to store the projectile object
public GameObject Projectile;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    //If left arrow key is pressed
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        //Move the player to the left
        transform.Translate (new Vector2 (-Speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));

    //If right arrow key is pressed
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow))
        //Move the player to the right
        transform.Translate (new Vector2 (Speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));

    //If the spacebar is pressed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        //Instatiate a new projectile prefab 2 units above the Player sprite
        Instantiate (Projectile, transform.position + transform.up * 2, Quaternion.identity);
        //Find the game object with the tag "Projectile" and call the DecreaseProjectileCount() function from the ProjectileTracker script
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Projectile").GetComponent<ProjectileTracker>().DecreaseProjectileCount();
    }
}
```

}

ProjectileTracker script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ProjectileTracker : MonoBehaviour {

//Variable to store the current projectile count
public GameObject ProjectileRef;
//Set the current projectile count to be 8
int CurrentProjectileCount = 8;

//Function to decrease the current projectile count
public void DecreaseProjectileCount()
{
    //Decrease the current projectile count by 1
    CurrentProjectileCount--;
    //Print out the current projectile count
    ProjectileRef.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = CurrentProjecileCount.ToString ();
}
```

}

Any form of help is appreciated!

Comment: Surely you would just check the current project count (which you declare as an int with a value of 8). If(CurrentProjectileCount > 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i would personally do it:

```
ProjectileTracker tracker = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Projectile").GetComponent<ProjectileTracker>();

//If the spacebar is pressed
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && tracker.ProjectileCount > 0) 
{
    //Instatiate a new projectile prefab 2 units above the Player sprite
    Instantiate (Projectile, transform.position + transform.up * 2, Quaternion.identity);
    //Find the game object with the tag "Projectile" and call the     DecreaseProjectileCount() function from the ProjectileTracker script
    tracker.ProjectileCount--;
}
```

...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ProjectileTracker : MonoBehaviour {

    //Variable to store the current projectile count
    public GameObject ProjectileRef;
    //Set the current projectile count to be 8
    private int projectileCount = 8;

    public int ProjectileCount
    {
        get { return projectileCount; }
        set { SetProjectileCount(value); }
    }

    //Function to decrease the current projectile count
    public void SetProjectileCount(int value)
    {
        projectileCount = value;
        //Print out the current projectile count
        ProjectileRef.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: cleaned it up a bit, it should be a lil better now